# Авторизация в стиме [RSA шифрование]

Tags: delphi, криптография, rsa, шифрование

никак не получается авторизоваться в стиме. Что я делаю:
проснифаф я понял что вначале идёт пост запрос с такими данными username=тут логин
ответ от сервера получаю в таком виде:

```
{"success":true,"publickey_mod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publickey_exp":"010001","timestamp":"551071900000"}
```

то есть я получаю 3 параметра publickey_mod, publickey_exp, timestamp

теперь собственно к сути проблемы затем пароль шифруется RSA шифрованием, но насколько мне известно чтобы что-то зашифровать по RSA нужно знать p и q(то есть ключи) 
ну так вот что из ответа сервера является ключами и как вообще зашифровать, спасибо

Comment: Вы бы почитали что-нибудь про несимметричную криптографию. С чего бы это серверу пересылать свой вам закрытый ключ?

Comment: ну есть же программы(любительские) которые работают со стимом, вот и мне охота понять

Comment: Не знаю по какому алгоритму работает сервер, но общая суть работы с RSA ключами следующая:

- публичный ключ сервера: (publickey_exp; publickey_mod) (либо наоборот, я исхожу из того, что mod - значит на это число делим).

- подписываете свои сообщения данным ключом

- никто кроме самого сервера не сможет прочитать данные сообщения, следовательно ваши сообщения зашищены

Answer (score 2):

Вы неверно понимаете смысл асимметричного шифрования.

1. Есть ключи `P`, `Q` - ваши публичный и приватный ключи
2. Есть ключи `p`, `q` - публичный и приватный ключи респондента
3. Вам респондент высылает свой публичный ключ `p`
4. Вы в ответ высылаете свой публичный ключ `P`
5. Вы генерируете некий разделяемый ключ `S=f(p, Q)` - функция вашего приватного ключа и публичного ключа респондента
6. Респондент в свою очередь генерирует разделяемый (shared) ключ `s=f(P,q)` - функция вашего публичного ключа и его приватного ключа
7. Теперь самое интересное состоит в том, что `S==s` - за этим чудом лежит некая математика

Теперь если вы зашифруете ключом `S` сообщение и отправите респонденту, то респондент легко расшифрует его своим ключом `s` потому что он идентичен вашему ключу.

Теперь к сути вашего вопроса - ваш респондент вам выслал свой публичный ключ снабдив его (на всякий случай) временем его жизни и штампом когда он был сгенерирован. Вам надо выслать респонденту свой публичный ключ - ну и далее по списку.

Comment: В RSA обычно приватный ключ — пара простых чисел — обозначается как `(p, q)`. Думаю, ТС имел в виду это в своём вопросе.

---
Сорри, виноват, приватный ключ — это `e^{-1} mod (p-1)(q-1)`, где `e` — публичный ключ. А `(p, q)` — просто секретная информация.